# Bootstrap 4 put items underneath each other flex box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote the following code:

```
<div class="row d-flex h-100">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-center justify-content-center text-center">
        <img class="flex-item" src="https://image.com"/>
        <br/>
        <h2 class="flex-item mat-display-1">Ajax</h2>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to align the items within the column underneath each other instead of next to eachother, but I don't seem to be able to do it somehow. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding **flex-column** class to parent div

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-center justify-content-center text-center">
        <img class="flex-item" src="https://image.com"/>
        <br/>
        <h2 class="flex-item mat-display-1">Ajax</h2>                        
    </div>
</div>
```